# How do I alias python2 to python3 in a docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, docker

I am trying to set the default python in my docker container to be python3 and have set the aliases in the dockerfile. When I open the .bashrc file, they show up. As far as I can tell, it should work but the default python version is still 2.7. if I run which python, it will still point to usr/bin/python rather than python3. Same with pip. Can anyone tell me what the problem is? Here is the command I'm using to alias:

```
   RUN \
   echo 'alias python="/usr/bin/python3"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
   echo 'alias pip="/usr/bin/pip3"' >> /root/.bashrc
```

Does this look right? I am using ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Assume .bashrc and other shell dotfiles just don’t work in Docker; many common paths don’t run them at all.

Comment: Even if they are defined in the docker file? I know ~./ doesn't work but I defined an absolute path

Comment: `docker run myimage python ...` never sees any shell dotfiles at all; it will run `/usr/bin/python`, which will probably be Python 2.  (And also any script that starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python` will expect Python 2 and not 3 in any case.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You try to create a symlink for python bin

```
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python & \
    ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

other option is use `update-alternatives` for more visit [this site](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3
```

and another option is trying source the bashrc file after updating

```
RUN \
   echo 'alias python="/usr/bin/python3"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
   echo 'alias pip="/usr/bin/pip3"' >> /root/.bashrc && \
   source /root/.bashrc
```

---

I recommend seeing all options of python images on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python)

Tip: use `anaconda` or `conda` for managing your python versions ([conda site](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html))

Comment: could try using "ln -sf" in place of "ln -s" as the those links are likely to exist if python2 is already installed.

Comment: Doesn't the `update-alternatives` line lack a (mandatory) value for `priority`? The `--install` option seems to demand that. E.g., with a value of `1`: `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1` worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

The answer above is great, except it should be as follows:

```
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
```

Perhaps they typo-ed by writing `ls` which just lists the contents of the directory, rather than using `ln` which actually creates symlinks.