# How to change Python default version in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am using aws ec2 Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS and having trouble with Python and Docker.

The python default version on ec2 is Python 3.8.5. I have also installed Python version 2.7.18.

But when I run docker or my complete network, docker is using the default version, which is python 3.8.5. So this causes errors for all peers, oderer and couchdb e.g.

```
ERROR: for ca_peerOrg2  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

ERROR: for orderer.example.com  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

ERROR: for orderer4.example.com  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

and also the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in _raise_for_status
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.22/containers/26d88164408dec7c247e07d47f803fd3767731bb0cf9748d9d0285de89c1f49f/start
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 625, in start_container
        container.start()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/compose/container.py", line 241, in start
        return self.client.start(self.id, **options)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
        return f(self, resource_id, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1095, in start
        self._raise_for_status(res)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
        raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
        raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
    docker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint couchdb3 (4cc5.....): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8984 failed: port is already allocated'")
```

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55346068/how-do-i-alias-python2-to-python3-in-a-docker-container), which I couldn't apply to mine.

Do you know, how I can change it, so that my docker runs without the errors? Thank you.

Comment: Docker doesn't use your EC2 python. It has its own python. Please show us your Dockerfile, you use to build image.

Comment: As mentioned before your container has its own image of the file system and will have whatever you or the base container you used in your docker file installed into the image.  You can probably find an appropriate container  with a 2.7 python already installed.

Comment: I wouldn't use a 10-year-old version of Python, that's had no bug fixes at all for the past year; make sure your code works with Python 3.  At least the last error you quote isn't a Python error but a Docker container setup error.  A [mcve] would be really helpful.

Comment: Soo.... your docker file installs a 3 version  (note the ENV line).   also the line linked here: https://github.com/sandeepsinghsengar/docker-file/blob/main/docker#L30 is probably the item that installs the MP command in your container.  You might want to read up on the dockerfile syntax to understand what is going on in that file.